# Error in Ajax to load a new into a div on form submit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using the following code to submit a form and then using ajax to load the action page into a div on the same page but i am getting the copy of the same form again on clicking submit.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form1').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('GET'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('mP.php'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#res').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
});
        </script>
```

My form code is

```
<form method="GET" action="mP.php" id="form1">
<input type="text" id="identity">
<input type="submit" id="sub1" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Result screenshot on clicking submit
.
[image: Result screenshot on clicking submit]

Comment: what is the return signature of the method in mP.php? Are you simply returning the whole page?

Comment: `$(this).attr('GET')` this won't do anything unless you have something like `<form GET="the-attribute-content">` which is not necessary. You can remove the type altogether if using GET as it's the default for `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Also, $(this).attr('mP.php') will not return anything. You probably want $(this).attr('action').

Comment: @tintyethan ya i am returning the whole page but i want the Get data along with it.

Comment: change `url: $(this).attr('mP.php')` to  `url: $(this).attr('action')`

Comment: @Moob Its for database interaction.

Answer (score 0):

may be page post back cause this.Change your  button type to button from submit at your html as follow :

```
<input type="button" id="sub1" value="Submit">
```

and listen for click event of the button at your js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#sub1').click(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $("#form1").serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $("#form1").attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $("#form1").attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $('#res').html(response); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem of url: $("#form1").attr('action') that was causing the error.
Thnx 4 help